# Aluminum nitride hydrolysis

Tags: reference-request, hydrolysis

I wanted to ask some reference about aluminum nitride hydrolysis in water.
Specifically I would like to know if there is the formation of radicals or of some other reactive species.

Comment: Aluminum nitride $\ce{AlN}$ is made of one ion $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ and one nitride ion $\ce{N^{3-}}$. Both react with $\ce{H2O}$. The reaction is $\ce{AlN + 3 H2O -> Al(OH)3 + NH3}$. What sort of radicals do you want to introduce here ?

Comment: To avoid duplicities, it would help responders if you wrote what you had been already searching for and where you had been already looking for it.

Comment: @Maurice I have learned to take nothing for granted when it comes to chemistry. Many phenomena can be more complex than they appear to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quoting from this study[[1](https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=3060)]:

> $\ce{AlN}$ powders hydrolyze in moist air at room temperature, resulting in degradation of the powders. The initial hydrolysis product is amorphous $\ce{AlOOH}$, which is further converted to a mixture of polymorphs of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ (bayerite, nordstrandite, and gibbsite), forming agglomerates around the unreacted $\ce{AlN}$ core. In the hydrolysis each powder shows an induction period, which is attributed to slow hydrolysis of the surface oxide/oxyhydroxide layer. The powders produced by the carbothermal process show the longest induction periods.
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{AlN + 2H2O → AlOOH_{amorph} + NH3}   & \tag{R1}\\
> \ce{AlOOH_{amorph} + H2O → Al(OH)3} & \tag{R2}\\
> \\\hline
> \ce{AlN + 3H2O → Al(OH)3 + NH3}\\
> \end{align}
> $$

You can find a detail explanation of the reaction in that study.

**Reference**:

1. Jinwang Li, Masaru Nakamura, Takashi Shirai, Koji Matsumaru, Chanel Ishizaki and Kozo Ishizaki, *Hydrolysis of Aluminum Nitride Powders in Moist Air*, **2005**, DOI:  [10.2240/azojomo0111](https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=3060)